# Backup folders in Jenkins maven repository

Tags: maven, jenkins, gradle

I am using Jenkins with gradle build on windows system.
Jenkins is internally using maven.I have folder structure as blow
C:\users\.m2\repository\\
Inside the modulename folder I have multiple folder with version as below
1.0.1
1.0.2
...
1.0.50.
Can anybody let me know why we have these folders created each day.
Is it a good idea to discard or reduce the folder.if yes how we can achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

**Maven resolves versions of dependencies according to declarations in all your projects (pom.xml).**

If project A has :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
</dependency>
```

and project B has :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.8</version>
</dependency>
```

Then you will have both versions 4.8 and 4.12 in .m2 directory.

**Instead of deleting "old" versions first, I suggest you create a BOM (bill of materials).**

It's like a technical module where you fix all your dependencies and plugins versions. Then you have to use it in your Maven projects. After that, you can delete too old jars in .m2.

**Example of BOM import :**

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>xxx</groupId>
  <artifactId>xyz</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>My project</name>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>X</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <type>pom</type>
       <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
      </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```